# AngularJS - browser caching JSON data

Tags: angularjs, browser-cache, browser-history

I am creating an application using AngularJS framework.

The Problem:

When I jump out of my application to a different domain or a page and then when I use history back button to get back to my app, I get back only JSON. The same situation happens when I jump out of my app browsing back in history, and then when I use forward button to go to my app, again I get only JSON back. Back/forward works fine within my app, it happens only when I go to different domain.

Why is that? I think it is related to caching some how, because when I do back/forward to my app, no request is send to the server.

You can see what I'm talking about if you go to this url - *http://test.deving.cz/admin/prihlasit/*. Then go back and then forward.

My setup:

My app is configured to use HTML5 history API. For an url that starts mydomain.com/admin/ I always return an index.hmtl containing angular. Then for every other url in my app two requests are send out. One for the template and one for the data (the JSON).

Example:

`$routeProvider.when('/admin/page/', {controller: 'PageListCtrl', templateUrl: '/templates/page/list/', resolve: 'PageListCtrl.resolve'})`

PageListCtrl:

```
angular.module('page').controller('PageListCtrl', ['$scope', 'data', function($scope, data) {
    $scope.pages = data;
}]);
```

Resolve function:

```
resolve = {data: 
            function($http, $q){
                var delay = $q.defer();
                $http.get().success(function(data){
                    delay.resolve(data['data']);
                });
                return delay.promise;
            }
        }
```

How should I configure angular or my app to tell the browser not to cache the data and to always get the index.html and then let angular do the requests?

Comment: try adding datetime.now() to url templateUrl: '/partials/indexpage.html?id=' + new Date().getTime()

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal this will stop caching the templates, am I right? However, I need it to stop caching the data. The template caching functionality is desired in my app.

Comment: could you share controller code or resolve code where you are fetching the json .

Comment: You should do two things change $http.get() to $http.get({cache:false}) and on the server side set a negative date expires header so that browser does not cache the json

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal It doesn't work. I can set the expire header to whatever I want and it has no effect. However if I set it to some date or time in the future, I get the cached result everytime, not only when browsing in history (I need to use ctrl+f5 to get the index.html and normal behavior).

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem.
While I found a workaround to this problem, I think there must exist a better solution.
So if you have any more better solution please let me know.

The server side framework I'm using is Rails.
So I add the following code

```
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
```

These lines will prevent browser to cache your request, and you can detect whether a request is a XHR to decide add the above lines or not.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments Ajay beniwal suggested that to stop browser from caching, the url should be dynamic:

```
 '/partials/indexpage.html?id=' + new Date().getTime()
```

So if I do something like this in my resolve function:

```
$http.get($location.path() + '?id=' + new Date().getTime())
```

the app and browsing in history works fine.

However I feel like monkey patching a serious problem. So if anyone has a better answer that actualy solves the cause to the problem feel free to answer.